# How to have Conditional SASS for Internet Explorer

Tags: sass

I was wondering if there is way to have conditional statements in SASS for Internet explorer

FOr e.g. lets say this is what I am looking for:

```
.container {
background-color: black
}

if ie10 {
.container {
background-color: yellow;
}
}
```

I found a few hacks that work fine like for e.g.

```
@media screen\0 {
.container {
background-color: yellow;
}
}
```

This one works fine but it is a HACK!! And I want to avoid it because who knows when IE fixes this issue and then I would have to re-write my whole code.

Here is one more hack that works

```
.container {
background-color: black;
background-color: yellow\0/
}
```

So in this case the second statement is read by IE but not by chrome and Mozilla or Safari so this also does the trick but again, this is also a HACK!!

I dont want to use any kind of hacks in to my project because they dont have a certain life-time.

So is there anyone who has figured out a way to apply IE conditional SASS without using hacks but using something official.

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS 3.2 Media Queries and Internet Explorer Support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621430/sass-3-2-media-queries-and-internet-explorer-support)

Comment: @cimmanon I dont know how this is a duplicate of the question you posted. It does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could just import an ie partial (ie10.scss)

base SCSS

```
.ie10 {
  @import "ie10";
}
```

HTML

```
<!--[if IE 10]> <html class="ie10"> <![endif]-->
```